# MySQL with JDBC, without while loop, select doesn't work, with while it doesn't take next query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("D:\\folder\\mySQLFile1.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(s);
}
br.close();

String sbq=sb.toString();
String S1 = sbq.replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)","");
String[] inst = S1.split(";|/");

for (int i = 0; i<inst.length; i++) {           
    if (!inst[i].trim().equals("")) { 
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(inst[i]);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        // while (resultSet.next()) {
            for (int x = 1; x <= columnsNumber; x++) {
                String columnValue = resultSet.getString(x);
                System.out.print(columnValue + " " );
            }
            System.out.println("");
        // }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Without while loop, select doesn't work, with while it doesn't take next query.

Comment: Why don't you log each SQL as you run it, so you can see what it is executing?  Also -- is the replaceAll really necessary?  Perhaps that is corrupting some of your SQL statements.

Comment: _"doesn't work"_ please be more explicit. Do you get an error, if so what is it? Also make sure you post a [mcve]; currently there is no way for us to reproduce your problem without guessing about your input. I can see at least one problem (not calling `resultSet.next()`) which would lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `ResultSet` is very general propose interface and it is **cursor based**.

Here is quote from official documentation:

> A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The `next` method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns `false` when there are no more rows in the `ResultSet` object, it can be used in a `while` loop to iterate through the result set.

This is means you **have to** perform `next` to move cursor. [Here](http://images.slideplayer.com/31/9774137/slides/slide_9.jpg) is the graphical illustration.

**So why `ResultSet` is cursor based?**

To allow underlying implementation not load the potentially huge number of rows into memory. The cursor is the very common pattern to kind of scroll over the potentially big data. For example the [PgResultSet](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSet.html) uses [ResultCursor](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/core/ResultCursor.html) to do so.

**P.S.**
Also please always perform `ResultSet.close()` to free up resources.

Comment: Do you mean the next row set? Did you check whether you have multiple rows in the result set or not? Agree with @SamGoldberg, regular expression might corrupt the query string.

Answer (score 0):

First, in using `replaceAll` you must escape all character, one time for Java, and second time for regex.

So if you use a `\` in a `replaceAll` you must write like that `\\\\`.

Second, print with sysout the content of `inst[i]` before send it.